# Upload or Download, extract tar files to Data bricks Spark

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, spark-streaming

Just started with Apache spark . Got the Databricks Setup. 
Struggling to upload CSV & TAR files.

```
val publicPCD = sqlContext
    .read.format("com.databricks.spark.csv")
    .option("header", "true")
    .option("inferSchema", "true")
    .load("s3-us-west-1.amazonaws.com/db007/Postcode+Data+for+Consumers+FINAL2.csv")
```

results in:

> Error :org.apache.hadoop.mapred.InvalidInputException: Input path does not exist: /s3-us-west-1.amazonaws.com/db007/Postcode+Data+for+Consumers+FINAL2.csv

Ideal scenario would be to download a TAR file, extract CSV's and do some analysis.
Had a look at this documentation without any luck https://dbc-272bf360-dc36.cloud.databricks.com/#notebook/10137
https://dbc-272bf360-dc36.cloud.databricks.com/#notebook/10758

Any help appreciated .

Comment: layout & formatting, my friend, layout & formatting!

Answer (score -1):

This is how you do it .

```
import java.net.URLEncoder
val AccessKey = getArgument("1. ACCESS_KEY", "REPLACE_WITH_YOUR_ACCESS_KEY")
val SecretKey = getArgument("2. SECRET_KEY", "REPLACE_WITH_YOUR_SECRET_KEY")
val EncodedSecretKey = SecretKey.replace("/", "%2F")
val AwsBucketName = getArgument("3. S3_BUCKET", "REPLACE_WITH_YOUR_S3_BUCKET")
val MountName = getArgument("4. MNT_NAME", "REPLACE_WITH_YOUR_MOUNT_NAME")
```

fill it in with your own information

```
 val publicPCD = sqlContext
  .read.format("com.databricks.spark.csv")
  .option("header", "true")
  .option("inferSchema", "true")
  .load(s"s3a://$AccessKey:$SecretKey@$AwsBucketName/.../...")
```

change that last line to line up with the bucket location!